# Unable to unset Phalcon aliases

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I am using INVO example app from here:

```
https://github.com/phalcon/invo
```

I have copied all the files and set the db and base url.

It works, I can login etc.

however, I wanted to learn how to use redirects e.g.

I would like to use `contact-us` instead of `contact` without changing the name of the controller.

So, I created a file routes.php inside of the app/config folder and put this inside:

```
<?php
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);

$router->add('/contact-us', array(
    'controller' => "contact",
    'action' => "index"
))->setName('contact');

$router->handle();
return $router;
```

and I have created this in my bootstrap file index.php in the public root directory

```
$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

$di->set('router', function(){
    require __DIR__.'/../app/config/routes.php';
    return $router;
});
```

However, it's not working and when I try to access `http://localhost/test/contact-us` it works, but `http://localhost/test/contact-us` stopped working and I am redirected to the homepage.

If I (comment the route) do this:

```
/*$router->add('/contact-us', array(
    'controller' => "contact",
    'action' => "index"
))->setName('contact');*/

$router->handle();
return $router;
```

Neither `http://localhost/test/contact-us` nor `http://localhost/test/contact-us` works ;(.

If I uncomment it back. `contact-us` works but `contact` don't.

I guess it's b/c of `->setName('contact')` and it's stored in the memory or in some file.

how to get it back to the original state and "unset" that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two routes and each will work:

```
$router->add('/contact', array(
    'controller' => "contact",
    'action'     => "index"
));

$router->add('/contact-us', array(
    'controller' => "contact",
    'action'     => "index"
));
```

Or use [groups of routes](http://phalcon-php-framework-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/routing.html#groups-of-routes).

So, if you have ContactController and don't want to access it using /contact url you should add router to the DI container. After that the pages will be available only via router and default /controller/action request format will not work.